# I want to get data of first table only by writing eloquent $query scoped function

Tags: php, database, laravel-5, join, eloquent

Please tell me the solution if exists. This is my code:

```
      public function handleRequest()
      {
           if (request()->filled('location_id')) {
                 $this->notification = $this->notification 
                    ->whereHas('location', function ($query) 
                 {
                     $query->where('location_id', 
                             request('location_id'));
             });
          }
        return $this->notification;
       }
```

I want to get the data of the "notification" table only, but this query returns "Location" table's data too. I have to use the $query scoped solution.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try select function `select(['Notifiaction table column name'])`

```
public function handleRequest()
  {
       if (request()->filled('location_id')) {
             $this->notification = $this->notification
                ->whereHas('location', function ($query)
             {
                 $query->where('location_id',
                         request('location_id'));
         })->select(['Notifiaction table column name']);
      }
    return $this->notification;
   }
```